# Reasons to use COUNT instead of COUNT_BIG

Tags: t-sql

According to the documentation, `COUNT_BIG` behaves exactly the same as `COUNT`, but has 2 advantages:

- It returns a bigger data type; meaning `COUNT_BIG` [won't fail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) when `COUNT` [fails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks).
- It [allows](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2021/04/29/sql-server-difference-between-count-and-count_big/) creation of clustered indices on views.

Why ever use `COUNT`? Why not just always use `COUNT_BIG`?

Comment: There is no reason

Comment: `count()` is portable. `count_big()` is not.

Answer (score -1):

Probably for the same reason as why you would declare a variable as tiny-, small- or int instead of bigint?

Comment: No way. We are not storing anything here. We are just counting, which is equivalent to a for loop. On x64 (the most common architecture) there's no performance difference between 32-bit and 64-bit integers. (32-bit integers [can have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750459/944911) slightly worse performance, but negligible in practice.)

Comment: Well, even if it’s a loop it’d have to store the current sumed value somewhere wouldn’t it? 
Also, if you’d want to assign the value of the count-big to a variable you’d preferably declare that variable as bigint, instead of int.